# How to specify type parameters for At (map-like types) from Lens in Haskell type signature?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'd like to constrain the key type to be `ImageId` and the value type to be `Sprite` while leaving the concrete type of the map unconstrained, by way of the [At typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.3.3/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#g:1). Is this possible? I seem to get a kind mismatch and, based on the type signature, I don't see how to resolve it. My example:

```
data Game m e = Game {
  initial :: e,
  -- ...
  sprites :: (At m) => IO (m ImageId Sprite)
}
```

My error:

```
    * Expected kind `* -> * -> *', but `m' has kind `*'
    * In the first argument of `IO', namely `(m ImageId Sprite)'
      In the type `(At m) => IO (m ImageId Sprite)'
      In the definition of data constructor `Game'
   |
64 |   sprites :: (At m) => IO (m ImageId Sprite)
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`At m` provides `at :: Index m -> Lens' m (Maybe (IxValue m))`. Notice that `Lens' m _` means that `m` is a concrete type like `Int` or `Map ImageId Sprite`, not a type constructor like `Map`. If you want to say that `m ImageId Sprite` is "map-like", then you need these 3 constraints:

- `At (m ImageId Sprite)`: provides `at` for indexing and update.
- `Index (m ImageId Sprite) ~ ImageId`: the keys used to index `m ImageId Sprite`s are `ImageId`s.
- `IxValue (m ImageId Sprite) ~ Sprite`: the values in  a `m ImageId Sprite` are `Sprite`s.

You may try to put this constraint in `Game` (though it's still wrong):

```
data Game m e = Game {
  initial :: e,
  -- ...
  sprites :: (At (m ImageId Sprite),
              Index (m ImageId Sprite) ~ ImageId,
              IxValue (m ImageId Sprite) ~ Sprite) =>
             IO (m ImageId Sprite)
}
```

Note that I'm saying `m ImageId Sprite` a bazillion times, but I don't apply `m` to other (or fewer) parameters. That's a clue that you don't actually need to abstract over `m :: * -> * -> *` (the kind of things like `Map`). You only need to abstract over `m :: *`.

```
-- still wrong, though
type IsSpriteMap m = (At m, Index m ~ ImageId, IxValue m ~ Sprite)
data Game m e = Game {
  initial :: e,
  -- ...
  sprites :: IsSpriteMap m => IO m
}
```

This is good: if you ever make a specialized map for this data structure, like

```
data SpriteMap
instance At SpriteMap
type instance Index SpriteMap = ImageId
type instance IxValue SpriteMap = IxValue
```

you would not be able to use it with the too-abstract `Game`, but it fits right into the less-abstract one as `Game SpriteMap e`.

This is still wrong, though, because the constraint is in the wrong place. What you've done here is say this: if *you* have a `Game m e`, you can get a `m` if *you* prove that `m` is mappish. If I want to *create* a `Game m e`, I have no obligation to prove that `m` is mappish at all. If you don't get why, imagine if you could replace the `=>` with a `->` above. The person who *calls* `sprites` is passing in a proof that `m` is like a map, but the `Game` doesn't contain a proof itself.

If you want to keep `m` as a parameter to `Game`, you should simply write:

```
data Game m e = Game {
  initial :: e,
  -- ...
  sprites :: IO m
}
```

And write every function that needs to use `m` as a map like:

```
doSomething :: IsSpriteMap m => Game m e -> IO ()
```

Or, you can use existential quantification:

```
data Game e = forall m. IsSpriteMap m => Game {
  initial :: e,
  -- ...
  sprites :: IO m
}
```

To construct a `Game e`, you can use anything of type `IO m` to fill `sprites`, as long as `IsSpriteMap m`. When you consume a `Game e` in a pattern match, the pattern match will bind a (unnamed) type variable (let's call it `m`), and then it'll give you a `IO m` and a proof for `IsSpriteMap m`.

```
doSomething :: Game e -> IO ()
doSomething Game{..} = do sprites' <- sprites
                          imageId <- _
                          let sprite = sprites'^.at imageId
                          _
```

You can also keep `m` as a parameter to `Game` but still keep the context in the `Game` constructor. However, I urge you to just go with the first option of putting a context on every function, unless you have a reason not to.

(All code in this answer produces errors about language extensions. Keep sticking them in a `{-# LANGUAGE <exts> #-}` pragma at the top of your file until GHC is placated.)

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: The simplest option is not to use a parameter at all, `sprites :: Map ImageId IxValue`.

Comment: This is a very clear answer, and I learned a lot. One question I have, after playing around a bit with both suggestions: why not prefer `forall`? It seems like it less invasive as only one aspect of the code needs to be changed if this part of the API is changed again (well, hopefully only one part).

Comment: @bbarker There are some things you can do with one that you cannot do with the other. If you only want the functionality they share, putting contexts on the functions is the simplest solution (fewer language extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this using [module signatures](https://wiki.haskell.org/Module_signature) and [mixin modules](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-mixins).

First I [declared](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-packages.html?highlight=signatures#pkg-field-library-signatures) the following "Mappy.hsig" signature in the main library:

```
{-# language KindSignatures #-}
{-# language RankNTypes #-}
signature Mappy where

import Control.Lens
import Data.Hashable

data Mappy :: * -> * -> *

at' :: (Eq i, Ord i, Hashable i) => i -> Lens' (Mappy i v) (Maybe v)
```

I could not use the `At` typeclass directly because of [this limitation](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8441).

Then I made the library code import the abstract signature instead of a concrete type:

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# language DeriveAnyClass #-}
module Game where

import Data.Hashable
import GHC.Generics
import Mappy (Mappy,at')

data ImageId = ImageId deriving (Eq,Ord,Generic,Hashable)

data Sprite = Sprite

data Game e = Game {
  initial :: e,
  sprites :: IO (Mappy ImageId Sprite)
}
```

The code in the library doesn't know what the concrete type of `Mappy` will be, but it knows the `at'` function is available when the key satisfies the constraints. Notice that `Game` is not parametrized with the map type. Instead, the *whole library* is made indefinite by having a signature that must be filled later by the users of the library.

In an [internal convenience library](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-packages.html?highlight=internal%20library#sublibs) (or a wholly a separate package) I defined a implementation module with the same name as the signature:

```
{-# language RankNTypes #-}
module Mappy where

import Data.Map.Strict
import Control.Lens
import Data.Hashable

type Mappy = Map 

at' :: (Eq i, Ord i, Hashable i) => i -> Lens' (Mappy i v) (Maybe v)
at' = at
```

The executable depends on both the main library and the implementation library. The signature "hole" in the main library gets automatically filled because there is a implementation module with the same name, and the declarations it contains satisfy the signature.

```
module Main where

import Game
import qualified Data.Map

game :: Game () 
game = Game () (pure Data.Map.empty)
```

---

One disadvantage of this solution is that it requires a `Hashable` instance for key types even if—as in the example—the implementation doesn't make use of it. But you need it to allow "filling in" hash-based containers later, without modifying the signature or the code that imports it.